# How to transfer files from QEMU FreeDOS C: drive to host?

Tags: qemu, freedos

I have a Linux Debian system. I have QEMU running FreeDOS and everything works perfectly. There is now a need to transfer data from the QEMU FreeDOS C drive to the host. How can I accomplish this, please?

I am able to get data from the host to the guest by creating a iso file as shown below:

```
mkisofs -o ng.iso /home/aruna/qemu/NG
```

And I am able to read it by doing:

```
qemu-system-x86_64 -m 2048 -enable-kvm -hda c.hd -cdrom ng.iso -boot d
```

How does one go back the other way? I have a file in my QEMU/FreeDOS C: drive which I would like to transfer out to the host. Is there a work around, please?

Comment: FreeDos is still DOS . I have a DOS 6 VM. You can transfer files with a bus-connected CD-ROM drive or a USB Floppy Drive. I use the latter and it works fine. Windows 11 Pro Host

Answer (score 0, accepted):

#### I need to transfer data from the QEMU FreeDOS C drive to the host

Use the following procedure:

> To transfer files between FreeDOS and the host, stop QEMU and mount
> the FreeDOS image under the filesystem.
>
> ```
> mkdir -p /mnt/freedos
> mount -t msdos -o loop,offset=32256 freedos.img /mnt/freedos
> cp oldgames /mnt/freedos
> umount /mnt/freedos
> ```
>
> Reminder: never mount the image while QEMU is using it and remember to
> unmount it before starting QEMU again!

Source: [QEMU/FreeDOS - Wikibooks, open books for an open world](https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/QEMU/FreeDOS)